# Syntax error running "Hello World" in Atom Editor using Love2d

Tags: lua, atom-editor, love2d

I'm just getting started with Lua Love and just tried running

```
function love.draw()
love.graphics.print("Hello World")
end
```

When running the code in Atom Love opens showing the error

Syntax error: main.lua:1:''expected near'.'

What is causing the error and how can I fix it please?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I had initially function.love.load() and deleted the dot between function and love BUT did not save the file thereafter. UUps